# Dynamic Memory Allocation in Fortran77 code (PNL Allocator)

Tags: memory-management, fortran, fortran77

I am working on an application, which is written primarily in Fortan77.
Since fortran77 does not support dynamic memory allocation, the code utilizes the
PNL Dynamic Memory Allocator:http://www.emsl.pnl.gov/docs/global/ma/MAapi.html

However can someone provide an explanation for:

```
   int_mb(index + i)
```

what does `int_mb` and similarly `dlb_mb` return?

If `cost` is an integer, what would `dlb_mb(cost)` specify?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: please provide more of a code example.

Comment: after a quick look at the docs, those things appear to be simply the arrays that are allocated (they are declared in macdecls.h). What they return is specific to whatever you program uses them for.

Comment: MA gives you `index` after allocating a block, then `int_mb(index)` points to the first element in the block. If you allocated integers, then you have to use `int_mb` such that the array is seen as an integer array. Suppose you asked for `n` integer elements, then you get back `index` and you can use `int_mb(index)` up to `int_mb(index+n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> However can someone provide an explanation for: int_mb(index + i)

That sets (e.g. zeroes) allocated memory.

http://www.emsl.pnl.gov/docs/global/ma/MA_alloc_get.html

```
#include "mafdecls.h"

      logical ok
      integer mhandle
      integer index
      integer i

      ok = MA_alloc_get(MT_INT, 5, 'heap int block', mhandle, index)
      if (ok) then
          do 10 i = 0, 4
              int_mb(index + i) = 0
10        continue
      endif
```

---

> what does `int_mb` and similarly `dlb_mb` return?

`dbl_mb` that is.

From https://svn.pnl.gov/svn/hpctools/trunk/ga/ma/mafdecls.fh.in (user: anonymous, pw: anonymous) I'd guess they return the previous value at that mem. loc.; simply try out by invoking twice in a row and assigning different values, then trace the second return val.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize an array using `ma_alloc_get`, you specify what memory type you are allocating (int = `mt_int`, double = `mt_dbl`, etc.) and it gives you back a memory handle and an index.  The index is used to access specific values within the MA array.

Let's say you've allocated an array of integers and `index` is your index.  `int_mb(index)` would be the first element in that array.  Therefore, `int_mb(index + i)` would be element `i+1`.

`dbl_mb(cost)` would be the double located at `cost` in the double block.  `a = dbl_mb(cost)` would access this value while `dbl_mb(cost) = 123.45` would set the value, provided that `cost` points to an initialized block of memory.

I personally like to think of 'mt' as 'memory type' and 'mb' as 'memory block', since that's what they are essentially doing.  'mt' variables are internal integers so the allocator knows which memory block to allocate to and 'mb' calls are accessing specific locations on that block.

You can read more on their [API page](http://www.emsl.pnl.gov/docs/global/ma/MAapi.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Fortran 90+ dynamic memory allocation.  There is absolutely no reason for MA to exist anymore except as a historical artifact in NWChem.